# Cascade deleting or analog of this in ObjectBox

Tags: java, kotlin, cascade, objectbox

There is [an issue](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/79) on github, but now objectbox not supports cascade deleting.
Are there any other options to do this except manual removing?

For example, models:

```
@Entity
class User(val username: String = "") {
    @Id(assignable = true)
    var id: Long = 0

    @Backlink
    lateinit var comments: ToMany<Comment>
}

@Entity
class Comment(var text: String = "", var date: Date = Date()) {
    @Id(assignable = true)
    var id: Long = 0

    @Backlink
    lateinit var user: ToOne<User>
}
```

If I want to delete user and all his comments, I should do:

```
fun deleteUser(user: User, userBox: Box<User>, commentsBox: Box<Comment>) {
    commentsBox.remove(user.comments)
    userBox.remove(user)
}
```

But if comments will have its own children, and they too — nesting can be very big.

I thought to use `BoxStore.subscribe(class: Class<Any>)`, but it can't give me the instance of `User` to delete only his `Comment`s.

Can it be done without reflection and other bad practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there's no way around doing remove cascade manually. Code your own remove methods that take care of nested classes. It's usually a good idea to do this in a single [transaction](http://objectbox.io/documentation/transactions/).

Answer (score 0):

Of course Markus Junginger is correct (as he is the maintainer). Currently cascading deletes are not supported.

I just wanted to add that there is an open ticket for this feature [here](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/79).